# The order of shape keys and modifiers

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, shape-keys

Sometimes I get confused about in what order shape keys take into effect. Namely:

1. Do shape keys change the mesh "one by one", like the modifier stack, or they're more like "blended" equally?
2. Do shape keys take into effect before or after modifiers?

Comment: shape keys, if the Relative option is activated, will cumulate their effect if you push up each value. And I think they take effect before modifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shape keys are essentially a special modifier at the start of the modifier stack, so they are calculated immediately before other modifiers.

Order of evaluation for the shape keys is irrelevant. Shape keys just add a displacement vector to each vertex in the mesh. The displacement is the difference between the key and the basis shape.